# JQuery não interage com HTML gerado via PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Fala, pessoal. Tudo bem?

Estou trabalhando em um projeto e em certo momento faço uma consulta ao banco com PHP e jogo o resultado em uma tabela HTML gerada com o próprio PHP.

```
    $areaComumDAO = new AreaComumDAO();
$solicitacoes = $areaComumDAO->buscaSolicitacoesUsoAreaComum($codSolicitacao, $codSolicitante, $dataAbertura, $dataDesejada);

$saida = "";

echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>CÓD. SOLICITAÇÃO</th>";
        echo "<th>CÓD. SOLICITANTE</th>";
        echo "<th>ÁREA COMUM</th>";
        echo "<th>DATA ABERTURA</th>";
        echo "<th>DATA DESEJADA</th>";
        echo "<th>HORA INÍCIO</th>";
        echo "<th>HORA FIM</th>";
        echo "<th>QTD. CONVIDADOS</th>";
    echo "</tr>";


foreach($solicitacoes as $solicitacao){
    $saida = $saida."<tr>";
    $saida = $saida."<td>".$solicitacao['CD_SOLICITACAO']."</td>";
    $saida = $saida."<td>".$solicitacao['CD_MORADOR_SOLICITANTE']."</td>";
    $saida = $saida."<td>".$solicitacao['NM_AREA_COMUM']."</td>";
    $saida = $saida."<td>".$solicitacao['DT_ABERTURA_SOLICITACAO']."</td>";
    $saida = $saida."<td>".$solicitacao['DT_DESEJADA']."</td>";
    $saida = $saida."<td>".$solicitacao['HR_INICIO']."</td>";
    $saida = $saida."<td>".$solicitacao['HR_FIM']."</td>";
    $saida = $saida."<td>".$solicitacao['QTD_CONVIDADOS']."</td>";

    $saida = $saida."<td><a class='botaoAnalisar'>";
    $saida = $saida."<img src='../../../imagens/icone_lupa.png' height='30' width='30'/>";
    $saida = $saida."</a></td>";

    $saida = $saida."</tr>";
}

$saida = $saida."</table>";

echo $saida;
```

A requisição é feita via AJAX em um arquivo separado (arquivo principal) e como podem ver eu adiciono uma célula ao final de cada linha com uma imagem que, ao ser clicada deveria realizar uma ação.

Segue a requisição.

```
$("#buscar").click(function(){
        var _codSolicitacao = $("#codSolicitacao").val();
        var _codSolicitante = $("#codSolicitante").val();
        var _dataAbertura = $("#dataAbertura").val();
        var _dataDesejada = $("#dataDesejada").val();
        
        $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "actionAvaliacaoUsoAreaComum.php",
                data: {
                    codSolicitacao: _codSolicitacao,
                    codSolicitante: _codSolicitante,
                    dataAbertura: _dataAbertura,
                    dataDesejada: _dataDesejada
                }
            }).done(
                function(mensagem) {
                    if(mensagem != null){
                        $("#tabelaSolicitacoes").html(mensagem);
                    }
                }
            );
    });
```

Quando recebo a resposta da requisição eu verifico se houve resultados (parte do **if**) e se sim eu jogo a tabela criada dentro de uma div chamada **tabelaSolicitacoes**.

Minha dificuldade é que no arquivo principal não to conseguindo interagir com essas imagens que ficam na última célula de cada linha, nem mesmo conseguindo emitir um **alert()** para teste.

Poderiam me dar ideias de como fazer o JQuery interagir com esses elementos gerados em outros arquivos? Pois até agora a única coisa que deu certo foi fazer tudo no mesmo arquivo, mas por questão de organização prefiro manter em arquivos separados.

Obrigado desde já, galerinha ;)

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque esses novos elementos estão a ser Dinamicamente adicionados.
Então para poder interagir com eles o evento click tem que ser apontado para elementos dinâmicos gerados.

Em vez de usar `.click()` utilize `.on()` .

Exemplo:

```js
const table = document.getElementById('table');
const tableCell = '<div class="tableCell">Novo Elemento</div>';

$('body').on('click', 'div.tableCell', function() {
    console.log('Elemento Clicado!');
});

setTimeout(() => {
    table.innerHTML = table.innerHTML + tableCell;
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="table">
    <div class="tableCell">Elemento Antigo</div>
</div>
```

> Verifique também que não está usando o mesmo `id` para vários elementos.
> Utilize `classes` em vez disso.

Answer (score -5):

Munir, no seu arquivo você tem uma variável $saida mas o início da sua tabela está sendo escrita no código com o "echo". Acredito que se armazenar o conteúdo nessa variável e der um return, você terá a resposta.

```
$areaComumDAO = new AreaComumDAO();
$solicitacoes = $areaComumDAO->buscaSolicitacoesUsoAreaComum($codSolicitacao, $codSolicitante, $dataAbertura, $dataDesejada);

$saida = "";

$saida .= "<table>";
    $saida .= "<tr>";
        $saida .= "<th>CÓD. SOLICITAÇÃO</th>";
        $saida .= "<th>CÓD. SOLICITANTE</th>";
        $saida .= "<th>ÁREA COMUM</th>";
        $saida .= "<th>DATA ABERTURA</th>";
        $saida .= "<th>DATA DESEJADA</th>";
        $saida .= "<th>HORA INÍCIO</th>";
        $saida .= "<th>HORA FIM</th>";
        $saida .= "<th>QTD. CONVIDADOS</th>";
    $saida .= "</tr>";
 
 
foreach($solicitacoes as $solicitacao){
    $saida .= "<tr>";
    $saida .= "<td>".$solicitacao['CD_SOLICITACAO']."</td>";
    $saida .= "<td>".$solicitacao['CD_MORADOR_SOLICITANTE']."</td>";
    $saida .= "<td>".$solicitacao['NM_AREA_COMUM']."</td>";
    $saida .= "<td>".$solicitacao['DT_ABERTURA_SOLICITACAO']."</td>";
    $saida .= "<td>".$solicitacao['DT_DESEJADA']."</td>";
    $saida .= "<td>".$solicitacao['HR_INICIO']."</td>";
    $saida .= "<td>".$solicitacao['HR_FIM']."</td>";
    $saida .= "<td>".$solicitacao['QTD_CONVIDADOS']."</td>";

    $saida .= "<td><a class='botaoAnalisar'>";
    $saida .= "<img src='../../../imagens/icone_lupa.png' height='30' width='30'/>";
    $saida .= "</a></td>";

    $saida .= "</tr>";
}
 
$saida .= "</table>";

return $saida;
```